# Добавление значения переменной

Tags: php

Есть такой код (см. внизу). Нужно его повторить 5 раз.
В переменную $urltitle2 должно добпвиться знчение $i, т.е первый раз это 1.
С этим все понятно `<?php echo $urltitle2.$i; ?>`
Как сделать аналогичное со значениями

```
$control_menu_urltitle2[$language['language_id']])

$control_menu_url2[$language['language_id']]
```

нужно чтобы было не 2 а 21, т.е 2.$i, должно выйти

```
$control_menu_urltitle21[$language['language_id']])

$control_menu_url21[$language['language_id']]
```

Такая конструкция неверная

```
$control_menu_url2.$i.[$language['language_id']]
```

Вот сам код:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        $k = 5;
        for ($i;$i>k;$i++) { ?>
                            <div class="form-group sub-link">
                               <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" ><?php echo $urltitle2.$i; ?></label>
                               <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                                  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"> <img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /></span>
                                     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="control_menu_urltitle2<?php echo $i;?>[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo isset($control_menu_urltitle2[$language['language_id']]) ? $control_menu_urltitle2[$language['language_id']] : ''; ?>" />
                                  </div>
                                  <?php } ?>
                               </div>
                               <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" ><?php echo $url; ?></label>
                               <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                               <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                               <div class="col-sm-6">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"> <img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /></span>
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="control_menu_url2<?php echo $i;?>[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo isset($control_menu_url2[$language['language_id']]) ? $control_menu_url2[$language['language_id']] : ''; ?>" />
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               <?php } ?>
                            </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: используйте массив `$array[2][$i]` или просто `$array[$i]`

Answer (score 1):

Для составного имени переменной нужно использовать фигурные скобки:

```
$control_menu_url21 = ['test' => 21];
$control_menu_url22 = ['test' => 22];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) {
    echo ${'control_menu_url2'.$i}['test']; // выведет 21 22
}
```

https://ideone.com/fYGzkd

А вообще, наверное лучше для таких целей использовать массив.